# Can a constructor be declared `[[gnu::pure]]`?

Tags: c++, gcc, constructor, clang

Is the following attribute annotation valid?

```
struct s {
    [[gnu::pure]] s(): m(1) {}
    int m;
};
```

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html says about attribute `pure`:

> Calls to functions that have no observable effects on the state of the
> program other than to return a value may lend themselves to
> optimizations such as common subexpression elimination. Declaring such
> functions with the pure attribute allows GCC to avoid emitting some
> calls in repeated invocations of the function with the same argument
> values.
>
> The pure attribute prohibits a function from modifying the state of
> the program that is observable by means other than inspecting the
> function’s return value. However, functions declared with the pure
> attribute can safely read any non-volatile objects, and modify the
> value of objects in a way that does not affect their return value or
> the observable state of the program.
>
> For example,
>
> int hash (char *) **attribute** ((pure));
>
> tells GCC that subsequent calls to the function hash with the same
> string can be replaced by the result of the first call provided the
> state of the program observable by hash, including the contents of the
> array itself, does not change in between. Even though hash takes a
> non-const pointer argument it must not modify the array it points to,
> or any other object whose value the rest of the program may depend on.
> However, the caller may safely change the contents of the array
> between successive calls to the function (doing so disables the
> optimization). The restriction also applies to member objects
> referenced by the this pointer in C++ non-static member functions.
>
> Some common examples of pure functions are strlen or memcmp.
> Interesting non-pure functions are functions with infinite loops or
> those depending on volatile memory or other system resource, that may
> change between consecutive calls (such as the standard C feof function
> in a multithreading environment).
>
> The pure attribute imposes similar but looser restrictions on a
> function’s definition than the const attribute: pure allows the
> function to read any non-volatile memory, even if it changes in
> between successive invocations of the function. Declaring the same
> function with both the pure and the const attribute is diagnosed.
> Because a pure function cannot have any observable side effects it
> does not make sense for such a function to return void. Declaring such
> a function is diagnosed.

How does this interact with C++ constructors? If you think of a constructor as a function (that is named after the type) that returns a value of that type, then the default constructor of `s` can safely be marked `pure`. If you think of a constructor as a member function that gets a hidden `this` pointer passed in and then writes into that memory, then the default constructor of `s` cannot be marked `pure`.

Comment: A constructor is more like a function that takes a pointer this, the other arguments, and returns void.

Comment: Added to an existing documentation bug in gcc to include the answer to this question (plus several other questions): https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51971